# What does the file named " 0oo00|111|1|" do in flutter apk？

Tags: android, flutter, apk

It takes up a lot of space, I want to know what it does and whether it can be deleted， thanks!

[image]

Comment: This page would suggest it is malware... https://blog.pradeo.com/malware-google-play-food-app

Comment: what !!! this is the application I developed, I am sure it is safe

Comment: If you have large binaries that you don't know where they came from, are you sure? To expand on the above article, it appears that is part of some encrypted code packer by Tencent, called Legu. If you knowingly added something like that, great. If not, then I'd be concerned.

Comment: thanks! now i know, because I used Tencent APK reinforcement service